# std::thread gives "thread" is not a member of "std" error in C++ Builder 6

Tags: multithreading, c++builder-6

I tried to use `std::thread` like this, but it gave me a "thread" is not a member of "std" error: (`stdio.h` is included)

```
std::thread thread_obj(makeFile, 512, MEGABYTE, "file");
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::thread` was introduced in C++11 in 2011. However, C++Builder 6 was released in 2002, thus it predates C++11 by almost a decade. C++Builder 6 only supports C++98, hence the error.

C++11 support was first added in C++Builder XE4, which was released in 2013. And XE4 supported C++11 only under 64bit development - 32bit support for C++11 wasn't added until several versions later.

So, you need to upgrade to a modern version of C++Builder if you want to use modern C++ features.

Comment: I see, is there an equivalent for it in C++98?

Comment: @furybowser no, there is nothing like `std::thread` in C++98. So, you will have to either 1) derive a new class from BCB6's own `TThread` class, or 2) use the Win32 API `CreateThread()`, or 3) use a 3rd party wrapper like `pthreads`, etc. The real question is - why are you using a compiler/IDE that is over 20 years old?